# $ errors in inline mathematical equation

Tags: math-mode

I want to make the following in-text formula and I am a LaTeX beginner:

```
 \begin{math}$ES_{\alpha}$=$-E[R|R≤-$VaR_\alpha$]$\end{math}.
```

I do, however keep getting this message:

```
! Missing $ inserted. 
<inserted text>
            $
1.29...in {math}$$ES_{\alpha}$= -E [$R|R≤- $VaR_\alpha$]$\end{math}.The a.....
```

I have already tried to alter the position of `$` multiple times. Could someone perhaps explain in which cases is a `$` needed, except for subscript and superscript because that part is clear to me. I am interested in the use of `$` in the in-text mathematical equations in general.

Comment: `\begin{math}` is an alternative to `$` use one or the other not both, just remove all the `$` from your example.

Comment: Why not just `$ES_{\alpha} = -E[R|R≤- VaR_\alpha ]$` ?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\mathrm{Var}`

Comment: What he said!... (`$ES_{\alpha} = -E[R|R≤- \mathrm{Var}_\alpha ]$`)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `ES` and `VaR` are acronyms that stand for "expected shortfall" and "Value at Risk", respectively, I would write the expression as follows:

```
$\mathrm{ES}_{\alpha}=-\E[\,R\mid R\le-\mathrm{VaR}_\alpha\,]$
```

Here, `\E` is a macro that denotes the expectation operator. Observe that you should enter and exit math mode only one time each.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectation operator
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{ES}_{\alpha}=-\E[\,R\mid R\le-\mathrm{VaR}_\alpha\,]$
\end{document}
```